# How to show Token Transfer details on mumbai polyscan?

Tags: remix, tokens, polygon

I am developing a smart contract where I want to mint NFTs. NFTs are being minted and shown on IPFS. But I cannot see the Token Transfer details on mumbai polyscan.

Anyone know what is the problem?? Please help

Here is my contract Link: https://mumbai.polygonscan.com/address/0x69A66176A9d8E5EB207CA8Ed66bdBF318f965523#code

What I am getting:

[image]

What I should be getting:

[image]

Comment: I can't say for sure but after looking in the [polygon testnet](https://mumbai.polygonscan.com/tokentxns-nft1155) it seems it doesn't show those details for ERC-1155 tokens. It works in the real one [polygon](https://polygonscan.com/tokentxns-nft1155), perhaps you should ask their customer support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of research and retries, I have come to know that Mumbai Testnet does not allow ERC-1155 TOKEN transferred details to be shown in transaction details.

I deployed the same contract on rinkybay testnet and it was showing the ERC1155 Token transfers. But not on MumbaiScan. I don't know if it is the bug of Mumbai testnet or what.

Answer (score 0):

Mumbai explorer does not recognize this ERC721 token.

Displaying tokens is a special feature added to better display NFT transfers, but the explorer needs to index that token appropriately.

The token may have transferred, it's just not parsed and displayed on the special "Tokens Transferred" section.

Comment: Yes exactly. Thats what I am asking. The token has been transferring But it is not getting indexed on the explorer.
Mumbai recognizes this token I believe. I have seen various transactions that are indexing the NFTs. see here: https://mumbai.polygonscan.com/tx/0x30e08be202bd4c8fee46c7a86bef973dfd811b4475063503092ff0206e1ca5e2
And this: https://mumbai.polygonscan.com/tx/0xc475712ff9a10f2f0e703b0368855aaf0ca961dc913e8088245032de1874d269